# Assigning value to input textbox using pickaday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery plugin pickaday to assign the value to an input field based on user selection of date. I am using the below input field which has id datepicker, and using the javascript, I am trying to assign the value field of input with the formatted date. But I do not see the value getting changed, I checked the output using console.log and it is showing correct value but the assignment is not happening. I am also seeing [object Text] as input when I refresh this page.

I am also using moment.js for date formatting, below are the include files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/pickaday.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/pickaday.jquery.js"></script>
```

My input field looks like this

```
<input class="textbox" value="" id="datepicker" aria-label="Use the arrow keys to pick a date" type="text">
```

And this is the javascript I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var picker = new Pikaday(
{
field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
firstDay: 1,
minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
yearRange: [2000,2020],
onSelect: function() {
document.getElementById('datepicker').value = this.getMoment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
});
picker.setMoment(moment().dayOfYear(366));
</script>
```

How can I assign the formatted output of pick a day to value field input ?

Comment: check the docs about formatting, you may have to set format property and implement your own toString and parse function https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Take out the value attribute, the new data from the date picker will be the value
The input element has to be like this 
`<input type="text" id="datepicker">`

Comment: This is the input element, somehow it is missing from original post

    <input class="textbox" name="lddate" size="40" tabindex="6" required="required" value="" id="datepicker" type="text">

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it stores null value in database in this case. I would like my existing value field to get a value using DOM manipulation

Comment: Then it's your js code. Please use jquery datepicker. It's more simple and only thing you need to do is assign the date frame to an element and that's it